# How can i use a Collection for Tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection `_authors` with some entries.

I want to assign an author-tag to my posts via:

```
{% assign author = site.authors | where: "title", page.author | first %}
 {% if author %}
  <a href="{{ author.url }}">{{ author.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

I tested this with only a forename like `Bob` and it works. If I choose a fore and surname like `Bob Baumeister` for the title in my authors-collection it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this happens?

**Example Frontmatter post:**

```
---
title:  Building
date:   2017-01-11 16:22:51 +0100
author: Bob Baumeister
---

Content
```

**Example Frontmatter Collection entry:**

```
---
title:  Bob Baumeister
twitter: bobby
---

Content
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give an author entry example ?

Comment: It is probably due to the usage of the filter "first", that select the first string in the authors name, update the question with an example of a page.author example and it's entry in the data file

Comment: @ David: Yes, I added some examples above.

Comment: @user3473628 the above example works for me, which title did you try to replace?

Comment: @marcanuy It should be a link to list where all Posts from "Bob Baumeister" are listed. For me it only works with the forename. Example: If I use only "Bob" there is a link displayed in my Post. With "Bob Baumeister" not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `"` :

```
author: "Bob Baumeister"
```

## Update

```
<!-- Bob Bau => bob-bau -->
{% assign slug = page.author | slugify  %}

<!-- filter by the slugified title -->
{% assign author = site.authors | where: "title", slug | first%}
...
```

but I think that using an `authors.yml` file instead of a collection could give more flexibility:

```
 - name: Bob Baumeister
   title: bob-baumeister
   url: /bob-baumeister

 - name: Henri Beyle
   title: Stendhal
   url: /stendhal

 - name: Jon Doe
   title: jon-doe
   url: https://author.jo
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Tried it in my posts. But doesn't work. If I use only one name like `Bob`it works. And `Bob-Baumeister`works also. Only `Bob Baumeister` doesn't work...

Comment: That was the right way. Because the `page.author` was slugified and the "title" from site.authors not I added another tag to the authors-collection like `authors_slug` with the content `bob-baumeister`

Or is it possible to slugify the "title" as well?

Thanks!

Comment: and yes, you can apply the `slug` filter to whatever string you want, e.g `{% assign slug = "Title With spaces " | slugify  %}`